# jquery focus. firefox 10

Tags: jquery, firefox

Anbody have tested

```
x.focus();
```

work in  Latest firefox version?
All browser other  then firefox working fine.I also tried other method like timer and blur also not working.

Firefox version : 10

Comment: tell us what you are trying to achieve with x.focus()

Comment: you might want to look back at your code, it's working fine for me in firefox 10 for the focusing part.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, [works neatly](http://jsfiddle.net/upKsq/) for me (tested with FireFox 10 on Win7 x64).

Comment: If you create a button and ask if focus to first textbox it don't work at my laptop

Comment: @HafizanAziz, it's normal that your script doesn't work. It has plenty of errors. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/upKsq/9/ You should define the `testFocus` function in the javascript panel. And since it must be a global function that you are using in the onclick attribute you must select `no wrap (head)` and obviously in this case put your first focus in a document.ready.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/alien3d/nxjJE/ If you   tried to empty the email field and press tab.It wouldn't focus to email textbox. I have tested  other browser working fine(Opera,Safari,Chrome,IE)

Comment: @HafizanAziz, I get `$("#date").dateinput is not a function` error in your jsfiddle. Please simplify it in order to narrow down your problem. Don't post so much code, nobody is going to read it.